# Spring boot run ends successfully but embedded server is down

Tags: spring-boot

I am executing a maven spring-boot:run command which ends without errors but it's embedded server keeps down.

```
[CPRO][ INFO] [2019-05-30 10:01:03] [es.ja.ctpd.calcprod.CalcProdApplication.main()] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(179)] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[CPRO][ INFO] [2019-05-30 10:01:03] [es.ja.ctpd.calcprod.CalcProdApplication.main()] [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(185)] Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http)
[CPRO][ INFO] [2019-05-30 10:01:03] [es.ja.ctpd.calcprod.CalcProdApplication.main()] [org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarted(57)] Started CalcProdApplication in 10.351 seconds (JVM running for 13.681)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.806 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-30T10:01:03+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm working in a multi-module project. The comand I lauch is this (positioned in the \application folder)

```
mvn spring-boot:start -P dev -s <path>\settings.xml -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

I've seen that it [is possible to launch boot using java -jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html), but my application is a war so I don't know if I could use this option.

I've also noticed that from my STS IDE when launching the server (this works fine) there are some log lines *"AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT"* in the console that are not present in my command-line boot.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok, as @andy-wilkinson says, I had to use spring-boot:run, but I still had issues. I've finally been able to run my app with this setup:

1 - A spring-boot:repackage command:

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage -P dev -s <path>\settings.xml -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dstart-class=<myclass>
```

2 - Launch command with java -jar:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev application\target\application-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-exec.war
```

Two final coments:

- I'm aware I should use a different running profile, that'll be the next big step.
- I've had to delete a useles orm.xml file I had that was giving an XML parse error and now it runs without problems. There's only a tomcat cache log line during boot up that I'll ask in another post.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? Usually this is because you're missing a dependency such as         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your application from the command line using Maven you should use `spring-boot:run` rather than `spring-boot:start`.

`mvn spring-boot:start` is intended for use with integration tests and Failsafe. It starts the application and then moves on. It's typically followed by Failsafe invoking a number of integration tests against the running application and then an invocation of `spring-boot:stop` to stop the application. You're specifically running the `start` goal so there's nothing else to do and Maven exits.

> I've seen that it is possible to launch boot using java -jar, but my application is a war so I don't know if I could use this option.

An executable war (one built using Spring Boot's Maven plugin) can be run using `java -jar`. That is how it should be run outside of development, with `spring-boot:run` being intended for us only at dev time.